# WPF Design Time Data not binding when class has default constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind design time data in WPF. I have a viewModel and my design time data class inherits from View Model. I am populating the data that I want to see at design time in constructor of the class like so

```
public class SalesModelDesignTimeData : SalesModel
{
    public SalesModelDesignTimeData()
    {

        Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "001", Title = "Pepsi", CostPrice = 10.0, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "002", Title = "Coca Cola", CostPrice = 10.0, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "003", Title = "Colgate Tooth Paste", CostPrice = 8.0, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "004", Title = "Lipton Yello Label", CostPrice = 12.5, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "005", Title = "Sugar", CostPrice = 5.0, Quantity = 1 });
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:designData="clr-namespace:Tienda.UI.DesignTimeData"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Tienda.UI.Views.Sales"
    Title="Sales" d:DesignWidth="775"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance designData:SalesModelDesignTimeData,IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding Items}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

The problem that I am facing is VS is giving me an "Object Reference not set to instance of an object error" in my XAML file where I am setting the d:DataContext

If I remove the constructor from my class then the error goes away and it binding seems to work.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `d` is a namespace but you access and assign this `d:DataContext`, which is strange. The left side should be property, dependencyProperty or field but all those members belong to ***class*** or object. So what exactly is `DataContext` (used in `d:DataContext`) here? It is surely not a property, dependencyProperty or field.

Comment: @Hopeless I am still new to WPF so maybe I am making a mistake but reading articles on-line this seems to be the way to bind design time data like mentioned here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx

Comment: from your link looks like `DataContext` is an attribute but still I've never used something like that, it's some kind of the editor's convention/language rather than the correct logic of accessing elements. If `DataContext` is an attribute `d:DataContext` is still an access to a class, so it's a bit confusing and non-sense to see this `d:DataContext=...`. Maybe it's a way to set Attribute for some element in XAML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see design-time data-binding in XAML editor (it works in runtime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401885/how-to-see-design-time-data-binding-in-xaml-editor-it-works-in-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for that crap

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

as explained by user hopeless in the comment.

This will work and is the way to go.

```
<Window.DataContext>
            <designData:SalesModelDesignTimeData />
</Window.DataContext>
...

<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

// Complete code after you commented that he still can't see design time data

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SalesModelDesignTimeData />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfDataControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }

    public class SalesModelDesignTimeData : SalesModel
    {
        public SalesModelDesignTimeData()
        {
            Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "001", Title = "Pepsi", CostPrice = 10.0, Quantity = 1 });
            Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "002", Title = "Coca Cola", CostPrice = 10.0, Quantity = 1 });
            Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "003", Title = "Colgate Tooth Paste", CostPrice = 8.0, Quantity = 1 });
            Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "004", Title = "Lipton Yello Label", CostPrice = 12.5, Quantity = 1 });
            Items.Add(new SaleItem { Sku = "005", Title = "Sugar", CostPrice = 5.0, Quantity = 1 });
        }
    }

    public class SalesModel
    {
        public List<SaleItem> Items { get; set; }

        public SalesModel()
        {
            Items = new List<SaleItem>();
        }
    }

    public class SaleItem
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double CostPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image: Screen shot of design time data]

Comment: I removed the d namespace and bounded the data like you mentioned but it is still giving me the same error "Object reference not set to instance of an object". I was of the view that you need to include the above namespace because I want to bind the data only in design time and not at run time?

Comment: If you define a static resource or a datacontext in xaml, it is available at design time. I post answer after checking its accuracy. I will post screenshot of the same. wait.

Comment: Works perfectly! 

Thanks Anjum! your way is simpler and more cleaner. Marked as answer.

Comment: What do you mean "No need for that crap"? That's how you use design-time data. What you seem to be advising is to simply set the data context to the design-time data, which will also then apply at run-time.

Comment: You should better use d:DataContext and bind on designinstance, like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16402388/3111930 then you don't pollute your running Application with unnecessary creation of an instance of your Designtime Class.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the code that I posted works just fine.

This link helped me to fix the issue.

[WPF/MVVM setting UserControl.DataContext in XAML results in Object reference not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885528/wpf-mvvm-setting-usercontrol-datacontext-in-xaml-results-in-object-reference-not)

My constructor was creating chain of objects, one of which was throwing exception. Once I fixed that problem, the design time binding started to work.

Comment: The way I was trying to make design time data appear works also but Anjum's answer below is much cleaner and works perfectly so I accepted his answer and will use that technique to bind design time data.